# Fix Tic-Tac-Toe Minimax ai

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I have a board class which represents the game board in Tic-Tac-Toe, but my AI is not working. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

I am attempting to use a minimax type of algorithm to try and see what the best move that can be made on the board is, but I am getting strange results. Right now in order to test my code, I am just running the testAI() method.

```
public class Board
{
    private int[] board = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    private final int HUMAN = -1;
    private final int COMPUTER = 1;
    private final int[][] winList = {
            {0, 1, 2},
            {3, 4, 5},
            {6, 7, 8},
            {0, 3, 6},
            {1, 4, 7},
            {2, 5, 8},
            {0, 4, 8},
            {2, 4, 6}
        };
private int[] choice = new int[10000];
private int choiceCount = 0;
private int[] scoreArray = new int[10000];

public void reset() {
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        board[i] = 0;
    }
}

public void set(int index, int player) {
    board[index] = player;
}

public int[] set(int[] board2, int index, int player) {
    board2[index] = player;
    return board2;
}

public boolean checkEmpty(int index) {
    if (board[index] == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean isGameOver() {
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (board[i] == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean isGameOver(int[] board2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < board2.length; i++) {
        if (board2[i] == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public int chooseRandomSpot() {
    while (true) {
        int r = (int)(9 * Math.random());
        if (checkEmpty(r))
            return r;
    }
}

private String[] toStringArray() {
    String[] y = new String[9];
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (board[i] == 0) {
            y[i] = " ";
        } else if (board[i] == 1) {
            y[i] = "x";
        } else if (board[i] == -1) {
            y[i] = "o";
        }
    }
    return y;
}

public void printBoard() {
    String[] y = toStringArray();
    System.out.println("  a b c");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            System.out.println("a " + y[0] + " " + y[1] + " " + y[2]);
        } else if (i == 1) {
            System.out.println("b " + y[3] + " " + y[4] + " " + y[5]);
        } else if (i == 2) {
            System.out.println("c " + y[6] + " " + y[7] + " " + y[8]);
        }

    }
}

public boolean checkForWin(int player) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        int a = winList[i][0];
        int b = winList[i][1];
        int c = winList[i][2];

        if (board[a] == player && board[b] == player && board[c] == player) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean checkForWin(int[] board2, int player) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        int a = winList[i][0];
        int b = winList[i][1];
        int c = winList[i][2];

        if (board2[a] == player && board2[b] == player && board2[c] == player) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public int getMaxChoice() {
    int loc = 0;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < choice.length; i++) {
        if (scoreArray[i] > max) {
            max = scoreArray[i];
            loc = choice[i];
        }
    }
    return loc;
}

public void testAI() {
    int[] x = {1,0,0,-1,1,0,-1,0,0};
    board = x;
    printBoard();
    minimax(x,COMPUTER);
    printBoard();
    System.out.println(getMaxChoice();
    int[] y = set(x,getMaxChoice(),COMPUTER);
    board = y;
    printBoard();
}

private int score(int[] board2) {
    if (checkForWin(board2, COMPUTER)) {
        return 10;
    } else if (checkForWin(board2, HUMAN)) {
        return -10;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

private int minimax(int[] board2, int player) {
    //System.out.println("In here!!");
    int oppPlayer = 0;


    if (player == COMPUTER) {
        oppPlayer = HUMAN;
    } else {
        oppPlayer = COMPUTER;
    }

    if (isGameOver(board2) || checkForWin(board2, COMPUTER) || checkForWin(board2, HUMAN)) {
        return score(board2);
    }

    int amt = 0; // find the amount of possible moves
    for (int i = 0; i < board2.length; i++) {
        if (board2[i] == 0) {
            amt++;
        }
    }

    int[] scores = new int[amt];
    int[] moves = new int[amt];
    int count = 0; //the index of the moves array
    for (int i = 0; i < amt; i++) {
        if (board2[i] == 0) { //if the space is empty
            moves[count] = i;// appends the index of the next empty space to the moves array
            count++;
        }

        //int[] newBoard = set(board2, moves[count], player); //make a new board with each move
        //scores[count] = minimax(newBoard, oppPlayer);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < moves.length; i++) {
        //int[] newBoard = set(board2, moves[i], player); //make a new board with each move
        int[] newBoard = new int[board2.length];
        for (int m = 0; m < board2.length; m++) {
            newBoard[m] = board2[m];
        }
        newBoard = set(newBoard, moves[i], player);
        scores[i] = minimax(newBoard, oppPlayer); //populate the scores array with the final score of each move
    }

    if (player == COMPUTER) {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int indexOfMax = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            if (scores[i] > max) {
                max = scores[i];
                indexOfMax = i;
            }
        }
        choice[choiceCount] = moves[indexOfMax];
        scoreArray[choiceCount] = scores[indexOfMax];
        choiceCount++;
        System.out.println(choice);
        return max;
    } else {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int indexOfMin = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            if (scores[i] < min) {
                min = scores[i];
                indexOfMin = i;
            }
        }
        choice[choiceCount] = moves[indexOfMin];
        scoreArray[choiceCount] = scores[indexOfMin];
        choiceCount++;
        return min;
    }
}

public int getIndex(String r, String c) {
    if (r.equals("a")) {
        if (c.equals("a")) {
            return 0;
        } else if (c.equals("b")) {
            return 1;
        } else if (c.equals("c")) {
            return 2;
        }
    } else if (r.equals("b")) {
        if (c.equals("a")) {
            return 3;
        } else if (c.equals("b")) {
            return 4;
        } else if (c.equals("c")) {
            return 5;
        }
    } else if (r.equals("c")) {
        if (c.equals("a")) {
            return 6;
        } else if (c.equals("b")) {
            return 7;
        } else if (c.equals("c")) {
            return 8;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: What are "strange results"? What do you find out when you run this with a debugger?

Comment: My call to getMaxValue from the testAi function does not return the correct value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < amt; i++) {
    if (board2[i] == 0) { //if the space is empty
        moves[count] = i;// appends the index of the next empty space to the moves array
        count++;
    }
}
```

shoudn't this loop run over the whole board?
like

```
for (int i = 0; i < board2.length; i++) {
```

(don't know if thats your problem, just saw that and thought it may be incorrect)

Comment: WOW! I just fixed that part of my code and it turns out that now it runs perfectly fine!! It's always the little, careless errors that ruin the code isn't it ;)

Comment: @Tyler Yes and it always takes hours to finde these  stupid bugs xD The curse of computer science.